# Trying to set up a simple keyboard input in a c++ program. Using variables to store true or false

Tags: c++, input, output

So I don't know why I am having trouble with this. I have looked around and I haven't found an answer that made since to me.   Many said you `cin`, but it's hard to make a Boolean storing whether a key is pressed or not and it pauses the project until input is received.

My ideal setup would be a function I can trigger in the update loop that stores whether or not a key is pressed inside a boolean variable... something like this:

```
bool left;
bool right;
bool up;
bool down;

Update()
{
      Input();
}

Input()
{
    //Insert code for detecting whether each of the keys is up or down
}
```

If you could help me figure this out that would be great! Also my goal is to make a program with basically no major libraries (other then graphics and math) so if it can be from scratch only using c++ methods that would be great, but if that over-complicates things then go with the external library.

Also as a bonus it would be nice to store the mouse x and y.  I can figure out the window part (like where the Cartesian origin is), however I have no clue how to access the mouse.

Comment: Any solution is going to be platform / APi / framework specific, you'll need to be a lot more specific if you want help.

Comment: Are you writing an application that is Win32 or Console on a windows machine or on some other OS platform?

Comment: You may try the curses library for a non-buffered console interface. It has implementation both for Unix-land and Windows. Not the best thinkable design and you'd better adjust the colors for Windows, but works.

Comment: I wish I knew... Erm I am building a project for windows that will be built with Visual Studio... It will be a project that uses the glew libraries.  Which means there will be a console, but a drawn window also, all of the action will be on the drawn window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Windows-specific:

You can use [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to determine whether the keys are pressed:

```
const bool up = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP);
const bool down = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN);
const bool left = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT);
const bool right = GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT);
```

Comment: also what if I wanted to know the exact moment a key is pressed? So i can trigger code only on one frame.